$\left( x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^r f = m(m-1) \cdots (m-r+1) f(\boldsymbol{x})$
I am trying to solve the following problem.:
Let $f(\boldsymbol{x}) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) $ be a homogeneous function of degree $ m $, i.e., a function that satisfies $ f(t\boldsymbol{x}) = t^m f(\boldsymbol{x}) $ and $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ class. In that case prove that
$
\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^r f = m(m-1) \cdots (m-r+1) f(\boldsymbol{x})
$
I proved the case where $r=1$.I fixed $x$ and treated $t$ as variable, then differentiated.By the chain rule of differentiation,
$\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(t\boldsymbol{x}) = mt^{m-1}f(\boldsymbol{x})$
By substituting $t=1$, I obtain the case where $r=1, 
\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right) f = mf(\boldsymbol{x})
$.
By repeatedly using this, I thought it was
$\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^rf = m^rf(\boldsymbol{x})$
but I can't figure out where the error is.

What's the source of this exercise?

It is a Japanese math book.But There is no explanation.

To be clear, I wasn't looking for an explanation.  I was looking for the title so I can search for errata.  This would be hard if it's in Japanese, though.

As far as I can tell, this problem has a typo.  When $f$ is homogeneous of degree $m$, it seems

$\displaystyle\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)^rf\right)(x) = m^rf(x)$
$\displaystyle\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)^rf\right)(a) = m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-r+1)f(a)$

Note that the operator in each case is different (in particular, $a_i$ commutes with every $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ while $x_i$ only commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ when $j \neq i$).

Oh you're right, that makes quite the difference. It seems both OP and I went with the option the author intended yet was definitely a typo as you said. Good catch! (Might also explain the downvote I received, potentially? I don't know)

Thank you!I send an email to the publisher about the typo.

EDIT: See Brian's answer for why this answer is a bit flawed. This answer uses what would be Brian's second case, and likely either the interpretation desired by or the typo written by the original author of the problem.
Go back to this equality:
$$ \left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(tx) = mt^{m-1}f(x) $$
Taking $t = 1$, we get:
$$ \left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(x) = mf(x) $$
hence:
$$ \left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(tx) = t^{m-1}\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(x)$$
Thus this operation makes you lose one degree of homogeneity, which is why it's not $m^r$ but a falling factorial.
Indeed, what you want to do is then re-applying $\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)$ on $\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f$ this time, which grants:
$$\begin{split}\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^2f(tx) &= (m-1)t^{m-2} \left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(x)\\
&= m(m-1)t^{m-2} f(x)\end{split}$$
which then gives you, again looking at $t = 1$ and then combining equalities: $$\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^2f(tx) = t^{m-2}\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^2f(x)$$
and so by induction you get that $\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^rf$ is $(m-r)$-homogeneous (not $m$-homoegeneous!) with:
$$\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^rf(x) = m(m-1)(m-2) \cdots (m-r+1)f(x)$$

Thank you for your response!!However, I still don't understand where my answer is wrong.

@Maaaa You want to apply the operation $\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)$ on $\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f$ which is $m-1$-homogeneous, and not $m$-homogeneous. That is, if you replace $f$ by $\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f$ in what you did, then you'll have $(m-1)t^{m-2}$ appear, and so on with each step.

@BrunoB It would help if you used an example.  For instance $f(x) = x_1^m$.  What does it give?
